# Choose Your Own Adventure - syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

Here is what I have so far:

```
    puts "It's 9:05am and you just woke up to the sound of your alarm. You had originally set your alarm for 8:30am. 'good job' you think to yourself as you roll out of bed"
puts "you are already running 35 minutes late for work. Do you take a shower?"

print ">"
shower = $stdin.gets.chomp

if shower = "yes" or "sure" or "ok"
    puts "Good call, you kind of smell from having a sweaty nighmare of a dream."
    puts " You have a quick five minute shower and it is 9:10am. "
        puts "You work in 50 minutes.Do you: " 
        puts " Take another 5 minutes to goof off?"
        puts " decide to goof off later"

        print "> "
        jack = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if jack == "goof off"
        puts "you goofball"
            puts "you have work in 45 minutes. Do you:" 
            puts "1. eat breakfast "
            puts "2. take it with you"

            print ">"
            breakfast = $stdin.gets.chomp

            if breakfast == "1"
            puts "You notice all the knives in your house are missing and you "
            puts "wanted to cut up toast. "
            puts "This is unlucky but you use a spoon."
            elsif breakfast == "2"
            puts "you grab a kop tart, a knock off brand of pop tart you found at" 
            puts "Costco for $1 less" 
            else 
            puts "Well, doing that's prob better in the morning anyways"
            end 

    elsif jack == "later" or "goof off later"
        puts "your call"    
            puts "you have work in 50 minutes. Do you:" 
            puts "1. eat breakfast "
            puts "2. take it with you"

            print ">"
            poptart = $stdin.gets.chomp

            if poptart == "1"
            puts "You notice all the knives in your house are missing and you "
            puts "wanted to cut up toast. "
            puts "This is unlucky but you use a spoon."
        elsif poptart == "2"
            puts "you grab a kop tart, a knock off brand of pop tart you found at" 
            puts "Costco for $1 less" 
        else 
            puts "Well, doing that's prob better in the morning anyways"
            end 


else shower == "no" or "not sure" or "nah"
    puts "that is messed up, because you smell. but yolo time to leave for work."
    puts "on the way to work you wonder why you had such a strange dream." 
    puts "you begin to remember parts of it, an old house, the number 205..." 
        puts "on the walk to work you see an old house marked 205, do you: " 
        puts "Go inside the house, it looks abandoned and familliar" 
        puts "keep walking to work"

        print ">"
        old_house = $stdin.gets.chomp

        if old_house == "go inside" or "go in" or "go into the house" or "go"
        puts "you open the door and realize it was a huge coincidence and also not empty"
        elsif olf_house == "keep walking" or "walk" or "go to work"
        puts "you walk to work, and you get fired for being late." 
        puts "you walk back to the old house" 
        else
        puts "oh well, you fail"
        end
```

end

I Am getting an error that says: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end but for the life of me, I have end statements. I am not sure why it is not running. It also only lets you run the shower == yes regardless of what you say. If you say no to shower, it still outputs "good call" etc. any help or direct would be much appreciated!

Comment: Careful what kind of code you submit here. Keep it clean.

Comment: I have done something we pretty much never do here, and that is to edit the code in the question.  I did so to remove language that is inappropriate for SO.  I attempted to preserve the code's meaning for the purpose of the question being asked, and I apologize if I have failed to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]".

Comment: @WayneConrad, you did a good job.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in this line

```
if shower = "yes" or "sure" or "ok"
```

Notice that it is `shower = "yes"` where is should be `shower == "yes"`. What you are looking for is something like this:

```
if shower == "yes" || shower == "sure" || shower == "ok"
```

or something like this for readability

```
if ["yes", "sure", "ok"].include?(shower)
```

Comment: Also worth considering: `/\A\s*(?:ye[ps]|yeah|sure|ok(?:ay)?)\s*\z/` where you can make it a lot more slack.

Answer (score 1):

Re-indent your code properly, and you'll see there is an "end" statement missing. Also, there is a typo in your first `if`, you want to write `==` instead of `=`

About conditions, yours are broken. When you are writing `exprA or exprB`, ruby evaluates exprA, exprB and return true if one of them if true. So, when you are writing `shower == "yes" or "sure"`, Ruby evaluates `shower == "yes"` and evaluates `"sure"`.

Ruby can evaluate any object in a condition, the only case to return false is either the statement is false or nil. So, as `"sure"` is never false nor nil, the test will always be true.

You need to write `shower == "yes" or shower == "sure" or shower == "ok"`

Comment: Strictly speaking, in an `or` expression Ruby doesn't return `true` or `false`, it returns the last operand that's evaluated. If `exprA` is truthy it will return `exprA`; if `exprA` is falsey it will return `exprB`.